# Instagram API check if a user is live

Tags: php, jquery, json, instagram

is it possible to use the Instagram api and check to see if a specific user is broadcasting a live video? and if yes get that video information and possibly a link?

Comment: What does their API documentation say about it? Considering how much they keep limiting their API, I seriously doubt that they have support for it, though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I couldn't find any documentation for live video, thats why I'm asking incase I'm missing something :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do This work with INSTAGRAM :

**post a media**

**send a direct**

**see people story**

**see people is online or not**

and ...

this work you want to do is not  possible.

fore more information see instagram developer page and see what work you can do with their API :

http://www.instagram.com/developer